# СИ: Ввод строки в консоли с редактированием значения по умолчанию

Tags: c, ввод

Вопрос по чистому СИ.
Нужно ввести с клавиатуры (в консоли) строку символов. При этом программа сначала выводит некое начальное значение этой строки, и затем пользователь может ее изменить по собственному усмотрению.
Например, программа выводит в консоль приглашение:
"Введите ваш город: " и далее сразу выводит некий город по умолчанию (например, "Москва")
Далее пользователь может либо принять это значение по умолчанию (нажав enter), либо изменить его на другой город. И программа, соответственно, должна корректно считать все, что будет введено.
Какие есть варианты как это можно реализовать в консоли?

Comment: Если именно на "чистом С" - то никак.

Comment: имеется ввиду не си++, а просто си. И без использования графических интерфейсов, именно в консоли

Comment: Да, просто на С этого не сделать. Тут придется использовать системно-специфичный способ обращения с консолью, будь то WinAPI или форматирующие последовательности VT100, ну и также возможна ситуация, когда ни то, ни другое не доступно или надо еще что-то. Чистый С для работы с консолью и пользовательским вводом в общем-то средств не проставляет.

Comment: Понятно, видимо, в сторону curses нужно смотреть (если речь о линуксе)?

Comment: Посмотрите на [GNU Readline Library](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_toc.html#SEC21) и заодно на связанную с ней [Gnu History Library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC_Top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение я в итоге придумал такое:
Эмулировать нажатие нужных клавиш в отдельном потоке, во время ожидания ввода пользователя. Получается именно то, что было нужно (т.е. "значение по умолчанию" с возможностью его изменять).
Всем спасибо в любом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Классический вариант для диалогового консольного интерфейса — предложить вариант по умолчанию в квадратных скобках, а потом проверить, ввёл ли пользователь что-то:

```
#define BUF_SZ 80

//...

const char *default_city = "Москва";
char city[BUF_SZ];
printf("Введите ваш город [%s]:", default_city);

fgets(city, BUF_SZ, stdin);
if (city[0] == '\n' || city[0] == 0 ) {
  strcpy(city, default_city);
}
```